# signification de "jouer la game" dans la chanson "L'Amérique pleure" du groupe "Les Cowboys fringants"

Tags: genre, québec, paroles-de-chanson, emprunts

Dans la chanson "L'Amérique pleure" du groupe "Les Cowboys fringants"

Un passage me semble un peu bizarre:

> La question qu’j’me pose tout l’temps :
> Pourquoi travailler autant
> Éloigné de ceux que j’aime
> Tout ça pour **jouer la game**
> C’est si triste que des fois quand chu loin de la maison
> Assis dans mon vieux camion
> J’ai toute l’Amérique qui pleure
> Que’q’part au fond du cœur

Un peu de contexte, la chanson est plein de mot anglais, comme ils le font souvent au Canada.
J'ai grandi en France, donc avoir ces mots anglais me semble un peu étrange.

Mon problème ici, c'est que "game" se traduit par "jeu".
Donc la phrase serait: Tout ça pour jouer le jeu. (c'est une expression qui colle bien au contexte)
Mais pourquoi "la" pour un nom masculin en Français? Vue que l'anglais n'as pas de genre sur les noms, ne serait-il pas logique d'utiliser le genre Francais?

Mes questions sont donc:

- Ma compréhension de la phrase est-elle correcte?
- Quelle est la règle des genres pour les noms anglais utilisé dans une phrase Française?

Naturellement il est plus facile de répondre à ces questions pour francophone du Canada.

Comment: Je laisse la réponse à un(e) Québécois pur souche, et il y en a plusieurs ici, mais je sais déjà que *game* est un québecisme (pas un « mot anglais » mais un emprunt à l'anglais spécifique au français du Québec) qui désigne une partie (fem.), un match (masc.). « Jouer la game » est une expression. Pas de raison pour moi qu'il y ait une règle (je serais étonnée) et dire si c'est le masculin ou le féminin qui est préférable  me semble une question d'opinion et on pourrait en discuter pendant des heures.

Comment: https://www.dictionnaire-quebecois.com/definitions-g.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je suis québécois, ton interprétation est correcte pour ce qui est du sens de la phrase. La raison pourquoi on dit "la game" est parce que "game" remplace plutôt "partie" et non "jeu". On utilise surtout cette expression lorsqu'on parle d'une partie d'un sport quelconque.

> Ce soir, on va regarder la *game* des Canadiens. (Hockey)

> Veux-tu jouer une *game* de soccer avec moi en fin de semaine?

Donc en réalité la traduction serait littéralement "pour jouer la partie", mais le sens reste le même. Je ne crois pas qu'il y a une "règle" pour le genre des mots empruntés, mais évidemment on essaie de garder le genre de la traduction.